# Issues adding NSIndexPath as key and NSNumber as value in Dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, boolean, nsnumber, nsindexpath

Second object of `quickFilterDictionary` in `self.preferencesListFilterDictionary` is `nil`. How to add [`NSIndexPath`] index path (as key) and `NSNumber` (as value) in `Dictionary`?

**Note**: first object is added successfully, only the 2nd object is `nil` when I printed `self.preferencesListFilterDictionary` in console. May I know , what am I doing wrong in below code?

```
self.preferencesListFilterDictionary["price"] = 1000
self.quickFilterArr = [localizedStrOf("deliveryNowOnly"),localizedStrOf("rated")]
var quickFilterDictionary = Dictionary<NSIndexPath, NSNumber?>()
        for obj in self.quickFilterArr {
            let row = self.quickFilterArr.indexOf(obj)
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:row!, inSection: 0)
            quickFilterDictionary[indexPath] = NSNumber(bool: false)
        }
        print(quickFilterArr.count)
        print(quickFilterDictionary)
self.preferencesListFilterDictionary.updateValue(quickFilterDictionary as? AnyObject, forKey: "quickFilterDictionaryKey")
print(self.preferencesListFilterDictionary)
```

***console print:***

```
▿ [1] : 2 elements
    - .0 : "quickFilterDictionaryKey"
    - .1 : nil
```

To get above dictionary bool from number, I wrote following code -

```
func getQuickFilterValueOfIndexpath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        if let val = self.preferencesListFilterDictionary["quickFilterDictionaryKey"] {
            // now val is not nil and the Optional has been unwrapped, so use it
            let tempDict = val as! Dictionary<NSIndexPath, NSNumber?>
            if let boolVal = tempDict[indexPath] {
                return boolVal!
            }
        }

        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused on the difference between a Row, an IndexPath, and an Index.

In the following code:

```
let row = self.quickFilterArr.indexOf(obj)
```

If you option click on row, you will see that it is an object of type `Array.Index?`. It is not an row.

Also is there a reason you are using NSNumber, NSIndexPath and update value for key?  As opposed to Number, IndexPath and just updating your dictionary values with:
   preferencesListFilterDictionary["quickFilterDictionaryKey] = quickFilterDictionary

If you option click on quickFilterArr and it is an array of IndexPaths [IndexPath] - To reference the IndexPath at your chosen index in that array you would just do:

```
if let arrayIndex = quickFilterArr.indexOf(obj) {
//if your array is an array of Index Paths
//you would then pull the IndexPath object at the index you have defined above
  let indexPath = quickFilterArr[arrayIndex]
  quickFilterDictionary[indexPath] = Number(bool: false)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kayla Galway, you missed this statement - self.quickFilterArr = [localizedStrOf("deliveryNowOnly"),localizedStrOf("rated")]